# Outlook File used by another program and unable to fix

Tags: outlook

I have a corrupted pst file. I used norton go back to get older version of pst file. Scanpst tool did not work. The error message was file was used by another program. the task manager shows no other program operating. Would any of the virus program or spy ware be using. how do i change file out?

Comment: This question isn't really something for ServerFault - Outlook (and related `pst` file) is a desktop app. Maybe ask on SuperUser?

Comment: Refer to the following Microsoft KB article and check if it helps: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/244330

Comment: Reboot your computer and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press control+alt+del - select 'task manager' - select the 'Processes' tab - and make sure there are no outlook.exe entries in the list. If there are, click on it to highlight it and click end process. Say yes to any subsequent questions about whether you are sure you want to end the process.
Maybe this post can help you out. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82b432a2-12e7-46f7-b27d-46a1a94c23f7/how-to-get-outlook-recovery?forum=officeitpro
Good luck)

Comment: Thank you guys for your feedback and help. Sorry, that long time did not respond. This is because the issue was solved and I forgot to tell.) Thank you!